# Deploying Django app's local postgres database to heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, django-database, django-deployment

I am unsuccesfully getting my django app deployed on heroku to use my local postgres db.

My DATABASE settings are as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'foo',
        'PASSWORD': 'bar',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Everything runs fine locally.  Following the instructions from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django, I add the following bit a code to the bottom of my settings file:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://foo:bar@localhost/mydb')}
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

However, this produces the following error:

*OperationalError at / could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?*

My django app runs fine on Heroku, except when it needs to connect to the database, which is where it throws this error.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your local db must be accessible from the Internet. If it's not, then you cannot use it on heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Allow remote postgres access to your local db. [example](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html)
2. Change the settings file to something like this:

DATABASES = {

```
  'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
      'NAME': 'your db name',
      'USER': 'your username',
      'PASSWORD': 'password',
      'HOST': 'Your computer's IP',
      'PORT': '6122',
  }
```

Or you have to clone your local db to [heroku postgres](https://postgres.heroku.com/) and change your settings to use that db.

Comment: Thanks!  I've decided to just use the heroku postgres db and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, your current configuration defines the database host as `localhost` while you should be pointing it at your hosts public IP (or fully qualified domain name).

But this seems like an anti-pattern. You really should be using Heroku's development databases for this stuff, and if you have any local data you'd like to import there, just make a database dump and load it.