# while deplyoing django app on heroku postgres doesn't work

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, django-database, django-deployment

I am trying to deploy my django app on heroku server,i followed the instructions from this website https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction .it worked fine till , "heroku open" command.When i came to the part where i need to host my database using " heroku run python manage.py syncdb" command , it failed showing the mesage "OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?". I tried lots of fixes including the one suggested here [Deploying Django app's local postgres database to heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778422/deploying-django-apps-local-postgres-database-to-heroku) and http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html .I tried all the solutions including editing the "listen_address" = '*' and tcpip_socket='true' in postgresql.conf and editing the ipv4 and v6 values in pg_hba.conf to 
host    all             all             127.0.0.1     255.255.0.1  trust
host    all             all             10.0.0.99/32    md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0 .

But none of them worked .I am guessing the problem arises because heroku can not connect to my local postgres server.This is strange because i'm able to access the postgres server via pgadmin.

And also in the django settings.py looks like this

DATABASES = 
{
'default': 
{
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
'NAME': 'django_test',
'USER': 'postgres',
'PASSWORD': '******',
'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
Do i need to change this and use heroku's database settings instead??

Comment: So the postgres server is located on the heroku server, correct?

Comment: no its on my local system

Comment: but if i give the server url of postgres db that i created on heroku(which starts with "postgres//xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", it says can not translate the address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` on the server points to the server not your local machine. The reason why is because the server running your django code will try and resolve the dns name `localhost` and it has a pointer to `127.0.0.1` which is local to the server resolving that name. That will NOT point to your computer you are working on.

You need to get an instance of postgres on heroku and change `HOST: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to the IP address of your new postgres instance in your django settings.

Comment: if config on my system shows this eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:5f:7b:84  
          inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fe5f:7b84/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:332469 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:287358 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          "which i don't think contain my ip address"

Comment: No it doesn't. Will be easier to just spin up a postgres instance on heroku or add postgres to your current heroku server.

Comment: VOILA , it worked thanks man , i was using the url of postgres ,instead of host...thanks alot